# Sharepoint 2007: Pop up message on new announcements

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

Is it possible to display on a page a javascript popup message if there are new unseen items in an announcements list?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the pop-up to jump out even when the user does not refresh a page, you will need to develop a polling mechanism (using JS) and call a web service to find out if there are new items.
Otherwise, you just need to add a web part to the page that will do the check on page load.
We did something similar, showing the users how many documents there are in a document library that each user has not read. we used the SPAudit object to find our what items have been seen by which user. Of course it has to be optimized for performance, so we just check a few of the latest items, not all of them. We even added this to the quick links menu, so that next to each document library appears a number of document the current user has not read yet, it is really cool, very similar to what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the last time the user viewed the announcements in a cookie and read that out to compare against the newest item. You can also store that the user has closed the pop-up.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following resources. You can make it work with minimum alteration

- [Using Jquery In Sharepoint To Display Notifications For Open Tasks](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2009/05/07/using-jquery-in-sharepoint-to-display-notifications-for-open-tasks.aspx)
- [SharePoint Tasks Popup using JavaScript API](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/SharePointTasksPopup.aspx)
- [jQuery Ticker for SharePoint Announcement List](http://littletalk.wordpress.com/2009/07/23/jquery-ticker-for-sharepoint-announcement-list/)